# Passing a number into member function causes program crash

Tags: c++, class, pointers, pointer-to-member

I just started learning about pointers and how they can work as member functions. I started playing around a bit and eventually wrote this small bit of code:

```
class Animal
{
private:
    int *itsAge = 0;
    int *itsWeight = 0;

public:
    void SetAge(int age) { *itsAge = age; };
    int GetAge() { return *itsAge; };
};



int main() {

    Animal Lion;
    Lion.SetAge(3);
    cout << Lion.GetAge();

    return 0;

};
```

my question is why is my program crashing when I run it? In my mind I'm passing in the number 3 by value to the SetAge() function. Then, the copy of value 3 is stored in age which is then assigned to the value of the pointer itsAge. Is it because itsAge was never assigned an address? If so, does that mean initializing itsAge to 0, doesn't really prepare the pointer to be used?

Comment: Why are you declaring `itsAge` and `itsWeight` as pointers?

Comment: I suggest dropping the classes and member functions and learn how pointers work first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite your program as:

```
struct Animal {
    int age = 0;
    int weight = 0;
};

int main() {
    Animal lion;
    lion.age = 3;
    std::cout << lion.age;
    return 0;
};
```

No need for pointers. FYI your program is crashing because you are initializing those pointers to `0` and then derefencing them with `*`, which is Undefined Bevahiour.

Comment: Oh okay. Ya I know in general pointers as member variables aren't necessary. I was just curious as to why my program was crashing. Thanks for the insight !

Comment: Oh and quick question. Is it leading to undefined behavior because the compiler reads *itsAge first, before assigning the value of age to it? Just curious as to the oder of operations the compiler goes through in order to accomplish an assignment operation.

Comment: @Jason In `int *itsAge = 0;` you are initializing a *pointer* to the address `0`, which is usually reserved. Which means that when you do `*itsAge` you are telling your program to go look at the memory block at address `0` which triggers to OS error.

Comment: Ooooh okay, Never realized 0 was representing an address. Thank you very much!